# view is not updating after change in scope variable angular js

Tags: angularjs

This is my code to get the data from server.

```
sampleApp.controller('OfferController', function ($scope, $state) {

    var offersRef = firebase.database().ref('offers');
    $scope.offers = [];

    offersRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
      $scope.offers = snapshot.val();
      //$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); 

    });
});
```

Initially $scope.offers = []; is empty. It is getting filled up here. $scope.offers = snapshot.val();

But view is not updating. if i click any button or anything there on the same page, or go back and come again on same page. its getting updated.

Why is not getting updated as soon as data in available?  How to fix?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call `$scope.$apply();` after setting the value to update the binding after setting the value.

```
$scope.offers = snapshot.val();
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response. Its working fine. But what if $scope is not available? For example in Service also some place i am fetching the data like this? How to use $scope.$apply(); there??

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal you should use $scope vaiable if you are binding it to a view! , in sevices you must be using local vaiables and assigning to them

Comment: Not Actually. in service i am assigning like this. ProductService.Products = snapshot.val(); and in controller i am using same reference variable. like this:: this.ProductService = ProductService;

Comment: how do you bind that to a view without a scope variable? btw mark its as an answer if it has helped you

Answer (score -1):

If you use any third party code which is not in the scope of angular then it will not get updated, so you have to explicitly call `$apply()` method of angular. Angular monitors every time for changes to update view and it looks like `snapshot.val()` is not in the scope of angular so it is not getting updated on view.

You can go to this link:

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: This does not contribute much to previous answer. You can add it as an edit to existing answer instead.